# Is BindableBase not working with dynamic properties?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

In a class I have both `dynamic` type properties and value type properties that bound to the View.  And I'm using the [`BindableBase`](https://www.danrigby.com/2015/09/12/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-6-way/) abstract class to fire INotifyPropertyChanged events.  To perform some calculations in code, I also subscribed to `PropertyChanged` to catch when the `dynamic` property was modified.  But I had problems with the `dynamic` property not generating events.  The other properties generated events just fine.

I think the problem is related to `BindableBase` not handling `dynamic` type properties correctly.  But I don't understand why.  Can anybody shed some light on what's going on here?

Working example using INotifyPropertyChanged: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fQ9tKZ

Failing example using BindableBase: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgBMyv

Comment: This looks like a bug in the .Net framework.

Comment: @SLaks Are you able to elaborate a little?